# JD Edwards Tables required fields

Tags: jdedwards

Is there a way to see in JD Edwards or Solution explorer the required fields for an insert of data into a certain table?

When I insert data using a Table Conversion into an EDI Table (Z-Table) and run the EDI Batch Process, I get messages in my Work Center that certain fields have to be filled. This 'Try and Error' method is not the way I want to work ;) Do you have any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You will need to have access to OMW, Object Management Workbench.  If you do, pull the table into your Default Project and go in like you are going to make changes to the table.  Within that area, you should be able to see what fields are 'Key' fields.  Those fields need to have values placed in them in order for the record to be valid and then be saved.  Otherwise you stand the chance of creating duplicate records.

You can also look into the database at the table if you have that access.

Depending on the database, you may need to write to a view (SQL) or a logical (DB2) table.  There can be many of these and each one will have different Key Fields.

There was also a website out there that you could search for the table and it might have that information included if you are using a standard JDE table.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to review the columns in primary key constraint and unique key constraint in Oracle, SQL Server and DB2 database so  that you do not insert records which violates primary key or unique key violation. You should also be able to review the table definition in Table Design Aid but you will need to have the JDE E1 development client installed to review it.